# How to access a particular class attribute at runtime based on a condition?

Tags: java, class, object

I am a beginner at Java. Pardon me if its too stupid a question.
I am fetching a string input from the user in a variable comparisonEntity. if the input is "xyz" then I have to compare all the instances based on this attribute. (the same name attribute exists in class) If the input is "abc" then I have to compare all the instances based on this attribute. 
Also I dont want to write redundant code in if and else sections.
So is there something like 
objectname."comparisonEntity" 
"comparisonEntity" will be replaced by the attribute name of the same value.

Comment: Take a look at Java reflection

Comment: you can create  custom comparators, and place them in a map where key will be allowed input.

Comment: Can you explain a little bitmore what the class that contains the attribute is standing for? How do you access the instances of the class - are they in a collection, array or something?

Comment: @NiklasP:  It is way more simple. I have three instances created. I am iterating over them based on names.  lets say we take obj1.comparisonEntity     The thing is that comparisonEntity (string) should be replaced by the same name field that i have in class definition.

Comment: Am I sorry that I cannot understand what you're trying to do - maybe you can post the code of your class with comments?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, I think you can achieve this by using reflection.

So you have an instance of your class, and also an input string:

```
Test    instance    =   new Test();
String  input       =   "nameOfSomeField";
```

You can obtain a `Field` that corresponds to the inputted string:

```
try {
    Field   field       = instance.getClass().getField(input);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException ex) {
    // Field doesn't exist
}
```

And then you can do things like get the value of such field:

```
Object value = field.get(instance);
```

Notice that `field.get()` returns an `Object`. You need to cast it.